# Is there an easy way to install Linux similar to Boot Camp?

Tags: mac, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, unix

I've so far been using Disk Utility to partition my Mac's drive and install Linux, but is there an easier way to do it, using something similar to Boot Camp, or a third-party software application that will split your drives easily (and is not malware)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's disk utility is all you need to partition your disk.

It's what Boot Camp calls underneath the hood.  Most Linux distributions have adequate information to make a DIY installer, but if you want something as polished as Boot Camp I would recommend Boot Runner by Two Canoes.  It comes with support so you don't really have to learn anything other than how to install Linux as it manages the dual-boot environment very well.

- http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner